# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No qualifying bean of type 'XXX' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, configuration, microservices

This is a Spring Boot project.
My project is having another project as a dependency. Like this:
`SecurityConfig(my project) extends AbstractSecurityConfig(dependency project)`

And this is the AbstractSecurityConfig code part:

```
public abstract class AbstractSecurityConfig {

    private SatValidationConfiguration satValidationConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    private SatConfig satConfig;
```

And this is the SatConfig (dependency project) code part.

```
@Lazy
@Component
public class SatConfig {

    @Value("${satKeysDir:/etc/satKeys}")
    private String satKeysDir;

    @Value("${pubSatKeys:test.pub}")
    private List<String> pubSatKeys;

    @Value("${pubSatKeysUrl:https://sat-prod.codebig2.net/keys}")
    private String pubSatKeysUrl;

    @Value("${satGracePeriod:1000}")
    private int satGracePeriod;

    private KeyResolverV1 keyResolver;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        final File keyFolder = new File(satKeysDir);
        keyFolder.mkdirs();
        .....
    }
    .....
}
```

I tried unit testing.

But all unit tests are failing.
I'm encountering an issue with my Spring application where I'm getting an UnsatisfiedDependencyException with the following error message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'satConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.yyy.SatConfig' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have a class SatConfig that is annotated with @Component and has the necessary @Value annotations to inject properties. However, it seems that Spring is unable to find a qualifying bean of type SatConfig during the bean creation process.

- Verified that the SatConfig class is being scanned by Spring. The package containing SatConfig is included in the component scan configuration.

  ```
  @EnableScheduling
  @EnableCaching
  @EnableConfigurationProperties()
  @SpringBootApplication(
      scanBasePackageClasses = Application.class,
      scanBasePackages = {
          "com.xxx.my_project",
          "com.yyy.dependency_project"
      })
  public class Application extends AbstractApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  ```
- Verified that the necessary dependencies for SatConfig are available and properly configured as beans.

  ```
  @Lazy
  @Component
  public class SatConfig {
  ```

Comment: I wonder if you shouldn't remove `scanBasePackageClasses = Application.class` from your `@SpringBootApplication` declarations. `AbstractSecurityConfig`, `SatConfig`... are I think, in the `com.xxx.my_project` or `com.yyy.dependency_project` packages? Their packages declaration aren't shown.

Comment: `SatConfig` is in `com.yyy` -- add that to `scanBasePackages`.

Comment: Could you show the test class?

Comment: Sorry.
I have solved this problem after add this code to test config class.

  @Bean
  public SatConfig satConfig() {
    SatConfig satConfig = EasyMock.createMock(SatConfig.class);
    return satConfig;
  }

Comment: For unknown reasons, this question got 140,000 views in about 90 days (more than 1,500 per day on average).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define SatConfig as Bean at the Test file separately. Clone the class to the test folder and use @TestConfiguration annotation. Then Spring Boot will see the bean at the test. Also you can define separate properties file for test. It solved for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).